# Supervisor - Start a django app and keep it running via bash file

Tags: python, django, bash, supervisord

I'm basically trying to do as the title says - keep a django app running, even on server restart.

I followed a few tutorials, but have not been successful in getting supervisord to handle this task for me.

I currently have a `conf` called `MyConf.conf` at `/etc/supervisor/conf.d`, that looks like:

```
[program:MyConf]
command = /home/user/virtualenv/gunicorn_start.bash                                                         ; Command to start app
autostart=true                                                                                          ; start app when system starts
autorestart=true                                                                                        ; defines how app starts in event app exits
user=vanew                                                                                              ; User to run as
stdout_logfile=/home/user/virtualenv/nginxConfiguration/error/gunicorn_supervisor.log                  ; Where to write log messages
stderr_logfile=/home/user/virtualenv/nginxConfiguration/error/gunicorn_supervisor_error.log            ; Where to write log error messages
redirect_stderr = true
```

**gunicorn_start.bash**

```
   #!/bin/bash
    NAME="myapp"                                            # Name of the application
    DJANGODIR=/home/useros/virtualenv/MyConf/myapp              # Django project directory
    #SOCKFILE=/webapps/hello_django/run/gunicorn.sock           # we will communicte using this unix socket
    USER=user                                                   # the user to run as
    GROUP=user                                                  # the group to run as
    NUM_WORKERS=5                                               # how many worker processes should Gunicorn
    DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=MyConf.settings                      # which settings file should Django use
    DJANGO_WSGI_MODULE=MyConf.wsgi                              # WSGI module name

    echo "Starting $NAME"

    # Activate the virtual environment
    cd $DJANGODIR
    source ../../bin/activate
    export DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=$DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE
    export PYTHONPATH=$DJANGODIR:$PYTHONPATH

    # Create the run directory if it doesn't exist
    RUNDIR=$(dirname $SOCKFILE)
    test -d $RUNDIR || mkdir -p $RUNDIR

    # Start your Django Unicorn
    # Programs meant to be run under supervisor should not daemonize themselves (do not use --daemon)
    exec /usr/local/bin/gunicorn ${DJANGO_WSGI_MODULE}:application \
    --name $NAME \
    --workers $NUM_WORKERS \
    --user=$USER --group=$GROUP \
    --log-level=debug \
    --bind=unix:$SOCKFILE
```

It keeps giving me an error of the below in the `stdout_logfile` file of, when I run the following command: `sudo supervisorctl start MyConf`:

```
Starting myapp
dirname: missing operand
Try 'dirname --help' for more information.
2014-06-14 01:20:15 [3698] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 18.0
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/gunicorn", line 9, in <module>
    load_entry_point('gunicorn==18.0', 'console_scripts', 'gunicorn')()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 71, in run
    WSGIApplication("%(prog)s [OPTIONS] [APP_MODULE]").run()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 143, in run
    Arbiter(self).run()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 172, in run
    self.start()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 134, in start
    self.LISTENERS = create_sockets(self.cfg, self.log)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gunicorn/sock.py", line 198, in create_sockets
    sock = sock_type(addr, conf, log)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gunicorn/sock.py", line 102, in __init__
    super(UnixSocket, self).__init__(addr, conf, log, fd=fd)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gunicorn/sock.py", line 31, in __init__
    self.sock = self.set_options(sock, bound=(fd is not None))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gunicorn/sock.py", line 42, in set_options
    self.bind(sock)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gunicorn/sock.py", line 110, in bind
    util.chown(self.cfg_addr, self.conf.uid, self.conf.gid)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 157, in chown
    os.chown(path, uid, gid)
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: ''
```

Note: `gunicorn_start.bash` has been made executable with `chmod +x gunicorn_start.bash`

Clearly it cant locate the file or directory, for something? How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you use just supervisor config to setup everything? It seems in your supervisor conf there value for `directory` is missing:

```
[program:gunicorn]
directory=/home/useros/virtualenv/MyConf
command=/home/useros/virtualenvs/MyConf/bin/python manage.py run_gunicorn -b unix:/tmp/gunicorn.sock

numprocs=4

user=vanew
autostart=true
autorestart=true

process_name=%(program_name)s_%(process_num)s
stdout_logfile=/var/log/supervisor/%(program_name)s_%(process_num)s.log
stderr_logfile=/var/log/supervisor/%(program_name)s_%(process_num)s.err
```